# window.hasOwnProperty() didn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm currently using this code:

`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(window, prop);`

But why it'd always returns `false`? I'm using Google Chrome btw.

Comment: Whats in the `prop`?

Comment: *"But why it'd always returns false?"* It *doesn't* always return `false`: http://jsfiddle.net/xx7wb2rh/

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not just calling `window.hasOwnProperty`?

Answer (score -2):

If the window property matches the value of prop then you should't be getting a false evaluation. 
Example:

```
window.e = "bar";
var prop = "e";
document.body.innerHTML = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(window, prop);
```

Comment: "Works for me" isn't an answer, it's a comment. A comment which [has been made](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143209/window-hasownproperty-didnt-work#comment50297062_31143209).